# Writing integers as sequences of products by 2 and integer divisions by 3

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, algorithms, partitions, integer-sequences

**For any integer, we consider its decompositions into sequences of products by $2$ and *integer* division by $3$.**

For instance:
$$
100 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 /3/3/3/3 \cdot 2 \cdot 2
$$

We consider such sequences of operations are done from left to right: $100 = ((((((2^{11})/3)/3)/3)/3)\cdot 2^2)$.

An *integer* division by $3$ means that we take the integer part of the result and discard the fractional part: $x/3$ means $\lfloor\frac{x}{3}\rfloor$ here.

We write such a decomposition in a compact way by omitting operators; then, the above decomposition of $100$ is $22222222222333322$.

This decomposition has **length** $17$. A **minimal decomposition** is a decomposition of minimal length.

It seems that (some of) the following questions are non-trivial:

- **do all numbers have such a decomposition?**
- **what is the minimal length of a given number decompositions?**
- **how many minimal decompositions does a given number have?**
- **how to find a minimal decomposition of a given number?**
- **how to find all minimal decompositions of a given number?**

This is a MO rephrasing and extension of [this math.se question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624680/create-a-number-by-multi-by-2-and-divide-by-3-integer-part) asked 7 years ago, that received recently some attention but still has no complete answer.

It was empirically established that all numbers from $0$ to more than $4535$ have a decomposition; that the minimal decompositions of $27$ have length $23$ and include
$22223222222233232322323$ and
$22222322222222333222333$; and that minimal decompositions of $4535$ have length $77$ and include $22222322223323222232222232323322223222232222222223222233322233233223333222233$,
$22222322232232322232232222323232222322232232222223232233222233222233222333233$,
and $22223222322232322232232222322232232232322232222222333223322233232223322322233$.

More observations are available in [the math.se discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624680/create-a-number-by-multi-by-2-and-divide-by-3-integer-part).

Comment: I guess the sample "decomposition" should have $/3$ instead of $\cdot 3$.
Every integer $n$ always has "decomposition" of the form $2^a / 3^b$ 
because (taking logs base 3) all we need is $a \log_3 \! 2 - b$ between
$\log_3 n$ and $\log_3 (n+1)$, and since $\log_3 \! 2$ is irrational
the positive integer multiples of $\log_3 \! 2$ are equidistributed mod 1
so in particular include infinitely many elements of the interval
$(\log_3 n, \log_3 (n+1)) \bmod 1$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: Does your argument give $b\ge 0$?

Comment: Yes, because there are infinitely many $a \geq 0$ and all but finitely many
have $2^a \geq n$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: Also $ \lfloor 2^n/3^k\rfloor \ne \lfloor ... \lfloor 2^n /3\rfloor/3\rfloor  ... /3\rfloor$ in general.

Comment: Actually they *are* always equal; in general, for any positive integers $x,y,z$
we have $\lfloor x/(yz) \rfloor = \lfloor \lfloor x/y \rfloor /z \rfloor$,
and likewise for $\lfloor w/(xyz) \rfloor$ etc.

Comment: This question should contain more explanation about how to parse expressions like $2\cdot 2 /3 /3$.

Comment: Thank you for these first comments, they helped me improve the question.

Comment: Also see an earlier question on MathSE: [Every two positive integers are related by a composition of these two functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/521449/16397).