# How many ways can $N$ be written as a sum of terms in the form $2^i3^j$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, polynomials, partitions

Given a positive integer $N$, let $f(N)$ be the number of ways $N$ can be decomposed as a sum of terms of the form $2^i3^j$, where each such term appears at most once in the sum. For example, $f(10) = 5$, since 10 can be expressed as $3^2 + 1, 2^2 + 2 \cdot 3, 2^2 + 3 + 2 + 1, 2 \cdot 3 + 3 + 1,$ and  $2^3 + 2$. I would like upper and lower bounds on $f(N)$ in terms of $N$.
I am also interested in the more general problem where we look for decompositions as sums of terms of the form $\Pi p_i^{e_i}$ where $\{p_i\}$ are specified primes.

Comment: Are $2=2^0+3^0=2^13^0$ legitimate decompositions?

Comment: Is this related to this question? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383675/writing-integers-as-sequences-of-products-by-2-and-integer-divisions-by-3

Answer (score 13):

The generating function is
$$\prod_{i \ge 0}\prod_{j \ge 0} \left(1+z^{2^i 3^j}\right),$$
which, by uniqueness of binary expansion, simplifies to
$$\prod_{k \ge 0} \frac{1}{1-z^{3^k}},$$
the generating function of partitions into powers of $3$.
See https://oeis.org/A062051

Comment: "at most once" versus "as many times as you want"

Comment: And the bijection is pretty clear: take all parts $2^i3^j$ with fixed $j$, and replace to corresponding number of $3^j$'s

Comment: Thanks for this response! I understand the bijection between the sums of N as 3-smooth parts and the partitions of N into powers of 3, but its still not clear to me how f(N) scales in N. Looking the first few values of f(N), it appears that f(N) grows polynomially in N. Does that sound right?

Comment: @Gautam: according to https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01182959/document, Mahler proved that the number of $b$-ary partitions of $n$ grows like $(\log n)^2/(2\log b)$.